Receive chunked response from server in frontend
I have a node.js/Express Backend API which returns its response with response.write(chunks) within a loop.
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

for await (const part of response) {
    res.write(part.message.content)
}
res.end()

If I curl the Backend API with a POST it returns the response in chunks, which is what I want it to do!
If I try to get the response via the Angular V19 webpage it appears that the response also is chunked, at least if I look at the network-timing

The image shows two calls to the API. The first call is the one with the chunked answer, the second call returns the response via response.send(content)
BUT: The following snippet only gives back one console.info(res) with the entire response
this.http.post<any>('https://example.com/posts', payload, 
{responseType: 'text' as 'json'}).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
        console.info(res)
    },
    error: [...],
    done: [...]
})

Any ideas?
SOLUTION
The comment from @Andrei gave me a valuable hint!
The final solution
this.http.post<any>('https://example.com/posts', payload, 
{
   observe: 'events',
   reportProgress: true,
   responseType: 'text' as 'json'
}).subscribe({
    next: (event: any) => {
       if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
          console.info(event.partialText)
       }
    },
    error: [...],
    done: [...]
})



http.post('https://example.com/posts', payload, {   reportProgress: true,   observe: 'events', })

@Andrei That works. THANKS!

Please do not add the answer as an edit to the question; if you are able to figure out the answer it is OK to add and accept an answer to your own question.
